# django restframework: blank=False and default='x' creates a modelsearializer with required=False field. how to circumvent?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

See example below, that will create a serializer with a not required `testing` field (obviously, as there is a default). I know I can add the field manually to the serializer, with `required=True`. But, having many fields, I would like to have DRF do the work for me. Or I could remove the default on the modelfield. Dont want this either...is there a thing, like `required_fields`, on the `Meta`, perhaps? Or another workaround?

Model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    testing = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False, default='x')
```

Serializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

The reason why I need this: Having a vue.js CRUD like app, that is creating new instances...without specifying the initial fields on the object.

Comment: If you don't add `null=False` and on the field, django will assume that the field is required by default. You should just drop the `default`. It doesn't make a lot of sense adding a default value to a field that is not a `boolean` or a `choice`.

Comment: Since you've mentioned about `required_fields` on the Meta, I think you can use `extra_kwargs` instead. [See docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

Comment: @Stargazer probably true. Got me - most of these are because I didnt wanted to go through the "Do you want to specify a default or quit and add one on the model" dialog when doing `makemigrations`. ;-)

Comment: @RieljunLiguid perfect! Thanks. If this goes into an answer, I will gladly accept.